# Unpublishing master branch incorrectly shows commits of remote branches in local master branch

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have been using a git repo on a local project I have been working on for the past few weeks. Recently, a friend wanted to help collaborate, so I wanted to put it all up on GitHub as a private repo. I initially just put all the branches up, because I didn't realize there was a way not to. After messing with git a bit more, I realized I could unpublish individual branches from GitHub.

I have 4 main branches: master, development, bug fixes, and sandbox.

I decided I wanted to only publish the development and bug fixes branches, keeping the sandbox local for messing around, and the master local to pull changes from development before uploading the files to the actual web server.

My friend in the meantime had made a new branch for the dragging and dropping feature he wanted to add, created some new files, and I believe he committed his changes to the branch he made.

The problem: In my Windows GitHub GUI thing

- When I go to look at my unpublished master or sandbox branches, they both show the commits my friend added to his drag and drop branch, which they shouldn't since drag and drop was not merged into them.
- When I look at the development branch, it shows the correct commits, without the drag and drop commits.
- When I publish the master or sandbox branches, then they will now also show the correct commits, without the drag and drop ones.
- When I unpublish them again, they once again start to show the changes in the drag and drop branch.
- When I open up a shell and type 'git log master' on the same unpublished local version, it does not list the commits from the drag and drop branch. It seems to only have this issue inside of the Windows GitHub GUI.

I wonder if this is an issue with the GUI or if its a user error, probably the latter. I don't understand the behavior of git fully yet, so it probably has to do with some status that is set along with the drag and drop files or along with the master and sandbox branches and I am oblivious to its existence.

Comment: Oh, I also just went to look at the working directory when the local unpublished master branch was the currently selected branch, and the files from the drag and drop commits were not there (as they shouldn't be), even though the commit history in the GUI shows they are. So it seems to be working correctly, but not displaying properly in the GUI.

Comment: I just switched to the drag and drop branch, locally, created a new file, committed the change to the drag and drop branch, and synced the branch. Then I tried switching to master and sandbox, and they both showed the new commits, while development did not. I made a new local branch called test branch, from the development branch, and it was showing the commits from drag and drop, even though they dont even exist in the development branch.

Comment: I published the new test branch, and the commits from drag and drop disappeared from it. I unpublished it, the commits from drag and drop came back. I made a new file in test branch then committed and published it. The new commit showed up in the sandbox and master branches. When the test branch is published, its commits show up in the unpublished master and sandbox. When the test branch is unpublished, the commits disappear from master and sandbox. When the test branch is published, and the master branch is published, they both show only their own commits.

Comment: I believe I have narrowed down the condition to only be reproducible when I am looking at an unpublished branch locally and it shows all published branches' commits, irrelevant of if merged, in the history of the GitHub for Windows GUI, but not in the actual working directory.